# How can I stop editText changing my text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have written a program to take text entered into an editText and pass it to another system via a USB/serial link.  I need to be able to enter fully arbitrary text and have it transmitted "as-is" without modification.
However, when I enter a string such as `4 2 .` or `SWAP OVER . .` the space between the final character and the first `.` is removed — what is returned in these cases is `4 2.` and `SWAP OVER. .`

Understandably, the target device doesn't recognise these and rejects the results.

I am entering the text into a textView cmdLine and returning it to my program using

```
cmdString = (SpannableStringBuilder) cmdLine.getText();
```

Is there a "feature" of `getText()` that tries to clean up the text entry, and, if so, how can I disable it?

Comment: Try cmdLine.getText().toString();

Comment: tried it - "Cannot cast from String to SpannableStringBuilder" is the result.

Comment: it looks as if this is a "feature" of the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 4.0.4 implementation - in Google, if I type q(sp). the search bar shows q.(sp)  If I use q(sp)(sp). it shows as typed.  I have tried the same thing with my Galaxy SII 4.0.3 and Nexus 7 4.2.2 and they both perform as expected.